# Flyway 1.5 & jBoss 7 migrate() returns 0 and sql migration is not applied

Tags: java, jboss7.x, flyway

Im trying to get Flyway 1.5 to work under jboss 7 and when I am calling migrate() it returns zero and no migrations are executed from the directory. baseDir returns db/migration and I have my migrations under PROJECT_ROOT/src/main/resources/db/migration. The migration file name is V1__Test.sql. I should mention that I have also tried by setting the baseDir explicitly and that the schema_version table has version 0 in it (as set by flyway.init()).

I have also tried this under Flyway 1.6 & 1.6.1 and i was getting a VFS protocol exception as I have seen under some known 1.6 issues.

Any suggestions?

Regards, 
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flyway 1.7 which has been released today should fix your problem.